# condition in regex

Tags: regex

I have a multi-line string like this:

```
@some text">
blabla bla bla">
@some te
xt">
```

I want to get the matches in the string which start with `@` and end with `">`,
like this:

Match 1:

```
@some text">
```

Match 2:

```
@some te
xt">
```

Comment: [`@.*>`](https://regex101.com/r/bVKeRE/1)

Comment: A good resource to learn [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/). I'm sure you can find many more online.

Comment: @Nikolas may be too greedy, fails with `@some"> <@string">`. Better use `@[^>]*>`

Comment: @mrzasa: I have included just the most naïve way since the OP is not familiar with Regex. Yet you are right :)

Comment: I know, I'm just overly sensitive to greediness as it's the most frequent mistake

Comment: @Nikolas but own text is 
some te (new line)
xt">

Answer (score 0):

the true answer:

```
\@\h*(?s)(.+?)(?=\">|\z)">
```

check this in [101regex](https://regex101.com/r/EFvkfO/2).